# Order of precedence of run modes AEM

Tags: aem

As per the adobe article the order of precedence of run modes is `jar file > sling properties file > system properties`.

> The run mode specified in the naming of the jar file takes precedence.
>   If run modes are not specified in the naming of the jar file, the
>   values in the sling.properties file are used. If run modes are not
>   specified in either the naming of the jar file or the sling.properties
>   file, the system property (or JVM argument) is used.
>
> Reference:
>   https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RunModeSetUp.html

In a different article the order of resolution is stated as `sling properties > -r option > system properties > jar file` (Reference: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/configure-runmodes.html ).

There are two types of run modes, standard and custom. The standard run mode is used at installation time and then fixed for the entire lifetime of the instance, they cannot be changed. The installation can be done by two means either by double clicking the jar or via command line.

Double clicking the JAR(which is not named as `aem<optional-version-or-indentifier>-<standard-run-mode>-p<port-number>`) sets the run mode as specified in the start script(system properties), `system properties > jar`.If the JAR is named as per the format, JAR name takes precedence, `jar > system properties`. The sling properties is out of the picture here.

Installing via command line using -r(`java -jar jarname.jar -r runmode`) takes the order `-r option > jar`.

Running custom run modes, the order of precedence is `sling properties > -r option`. The JAR name and system properties is out of picture here since the installation has done.

> ::* runmode(s)
>
> ::* will not be used if repository is already present
>
> if not defined CQ_RUNMODE set CQ_RUNMODE=author
>
> Reference: The start script(start.bat file).

Once the installation has done the JAR name and system properties has no effect in determining the run modes. Custom run modes can be set through `sling properties` and `-r option`. At the time of installation the precedence depends on the mode of installation and whether or not the file has been named in the format `aem<optional-version-or-indentifier>-<standard-run-mode>-p<port-number>`. Help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Adobe docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/configure-runmodes.html)

> **Starting CQ with a specific run mode**
>
> If you have defined configurations for multiple run modes then you
>   need to define which is to be used upon startup. There are several
>   methods for specifying which run mode to use; the order of resolution
>   is:
>
> 1. sling.properties file
> 2. -r option
> 3. system properties (-D)
> 4. Filename detection

Answer (score -1):

Order of preference of run modes in AEM :

1. File name detection of aem jar file (cq-author-p4502.jar)
2. start.bat file property : `-Dsling.run.modes = publish,prod` for example
3. -r option : java -jar cq-author-p4502.jar -r dev
4. sling.properties file under /cq-quickstart/conf/sling.properties

Double clicking the jar will set the run mode as named in the filename of jar. If you want to start from command prompt using
start.bat file, then the run mode defined in start.bat will be taken. 
Try the following : Copy the jar file and license file in any other folder, change the jar filename as cq-publish-p4503. Then double click the jar file, you can see publish instance has opened with 4503 port. Then check the start.bat file it will be still pointing to author and 4502, so it means filename of the jar takes precedence than start.bat file.Hope this explains your query

Comment: I got your point. Considering that AEM question how does option B become the answer, there's no mention about standard or custom run modes.